# How does one transfer data from an iPhone 6 to a Pixel 6 pro that has already been set up?

Tags: iphone, video, data-transfer, google, ios

So this is not the first time I turn on my Pixel 6 pro. When I connect the devices with a cable no options appear so it is unclear what to do next to transfer the data and the video I was watching doesn't suggest what to actually do:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1IPSE2avCE

and I've tried a bunch of things like google one etc but the contacts and the videos from my iphone 6 s are NOT on my pixel.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

honestly the main take away is to do it once during setup of the phone.

Otherwise see this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247469/376045

Will post it as a community answer since I'm not too happy that I had to download a third party app and that it doesn't seem to be using the cables I bought...I used the `Send Anywhere (File Transfer) app`. Instructions in video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEdVU96bol8 in text:

1. download `Send Anywhere (File Transfer) app`
2. choose the videos, photos, contacts etc from the iphone
3. choose the pixel to be a receiver
4. get the code from the iphone put it in the receiver
   then click send

done...or at least I hope the transfer happens. Going on right now.